# Can I have some feedback on this research paper on vibration diagnostics?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, wavelet, classification

I have submitted this paper "[Detecting a Valve Spring Failure of a Piston Compressor with the Help of the Vibration Monitoring](https://figshare.com/s/d78c6ee886987c037479)" to figshare.com.

I would like to get some feedback on the methodology of the same. Inputs of any sort are welcome. Can you please take a look at it and give me some feedback/suggestions/critics?

> Abstract:  The  article  presents  problems  related  to  vibration
>   diagnostics in reciprocating compressors.  This paper presents the
>   evaluation of several techniques of the digital signal processing,
>   such as the spectrum calculation with the Discrete Fourier Transform
>   (DFT), Continuous Wavelet Transform (CWT), Segmented Analysis for
>   detection the spring failure in reciprocating compressor valve with the
>   help of the vibration monitoring. The experimental  investigation  to 
>   collect  the  data  from  the  compressor with both the faultless
>   valve and the valve with spring failure  was  conducted.   Three 
>   112DV1  vibration  acceleration probes  manufactured  by  TIK  were 
>   mounted  on  the  cylinder of the compressor.   The keyphasor probe
>   was mounted on the compressor’s flywheel.  The signal of the vibration
>   acceleration probe  mounted  on  the  top  of  the  cylinder  was 
>   used  for  the Condition  Monitoring  and  Fault  Detection  of  the 
>   valve.   The TIK-RVM system of monitoring and data acquisition was
>   used for gathering the signal samples from the probes. The sampling
>   frequency was 30193.5 Hz, signal length was 65535 samples. To imitate
>   the spring fault, the exhaust valve spring was replaced by the
>   shortened one with the same stiffness. It has been shown what the
>   signal acquired from the vibration acceleration probe mounted on the
>   reciprocating compressor cylinder can be used for reliable detection of
>   the spring failure of the compressor’s valve  with  the  help  of  the
>   mentioned  signal  processing  techniques.   As  it  can  be  seen 
>   from  the  signal  processing  results in  the  article,  the 
>   techniques  used  are  showing  quite  different results  for  the 
>   cases  of  the  normal  valve  spring  and  the  short one.   It seems
>   what for this type of the compressor and valve, the  valve  spring 
>   failure  can  be  quite  reliably  detected  with  the help  of  the 
>   vibration  monitoring.   To  see  if  this  is  a  case  for other 
>   compressor  types  and  other  valve  types,  the  additional
>   experiments are needed.
>
> Signal processing methods: spectrum, wavelets, fragmentation,
>   decision trees (classification)

Comment: I'd suggest you to add for instance an abstract, and to mention the signal processing techniques (in tags as well) you are using

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP! Sounds interesting! I’ll give it a read later today and give feedback once I’m done.